# Material UI - Remove "Rows per page" in the component TablePagination

Tags: material-ui

How can I remove the select "Rows per page"? I don't want to use it in my project...

[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Correct answer you should find in documentation. For the property `rowsPerPageOptions` one says:

> Customizes the options of the rows per page select field. If less than two options are available, no select field will be displayed.

So you have to specify `rowsPerPageOptions={[]}`, that's all folks.
The documentations could be found [here](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/).

Comment: I didn't ask the question but just wanted to say that I'm sorry.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but it will show an error in Material UI 5: `Material-UI: The page size 100 is not preset in the rowsPerPageOptions
Add it to show the pagination select. `

Comment: It's strange. I try to set rowsPerPageOptions={[]} in https://codesandbox.io/s/goimt?file=/demo.js and no any error founded in console. Check your project please, maybe you have a mistake.

Comment: @FooBar I also had the same warning appearing in my console. I fixed it with `rowsPerPageOptions={[100]}`, which seems to have the same effect as an empty list or specifying any other number.

Answer (score 9):

Just assign the attribute `labelRowsPerPage` in `TablePagination` tag to an empty string.

```js
<TablePagination
  labelRowsPerPage=''
  {...otherProps}
  />
```

Answer (score 6):

I cannot comment yet, unfortunately.

But for MUI 5 I got an error when attempting the empty array.

It is possible that the cause is my pageSize is set to 5, so the following worked fine for me:

```
pageSize={5}
rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
```

This is an answer for the comment from FooBar:

> It's a nice solution, but it will show an error in Material UI 5: Material-UI: The page size 100 is not preset in the rowsPerPageOptions Add it to show the pagination select.  – FooBar Oct 26 at 14:26

Answer (score 5):

Just add the options property with paging as false to your JSX call for Material Table

```
<MaterialTable
    //your other props
    options={{
        paging: false
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Little different when you use MUIDataTable - it's 'pagination'
https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#mui-datatables---datatables-for-mui-formerly-material-ui

```
<MUIDataTable 
      //...
      options={{ pagination: false }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can set the label to '' and hide the drop down, here is how to access them for MUI `"@mui/material": "5.10.16",`

```
         <TablePagination
            component="div"
            count={100}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={handleChangePage}
            rowsPerPage={10}
            labelRowsPerPage=''
            sx={{
              '& .MuiSelect-select':{
                display: 'none !important'
              },
              '& > div.MuiToolbar-root > div.MuiInputBase-root > svg':{
                display: 'none !important'
              }
            }}
          />
```